# Problem: fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping (time-series analysis)

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, lme4-nlme

I have struggled with this statistical analysis.

My dataset is 5 replicates of plot, Mon to Fri of date, C or T of treat, and separated time (ex, Mon to Wed as beginning of week, Thu as end of week, and Fri as very end of week). There is dependant variable in v1 column.

What I want to test is whether treatment effect is significant depending on time, and also date effect.

Here are reproducible codes.

```
data <- data.frame("v1" = rnorm(100)) #generate data
data$plot <- as.factor(rep(1:5,10)) #add plot as random effect
data$date <- as.factor(rep(c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"),each = 20)) #date
data$time <- as.factor(rep(c(1,1,1,2,3), each = 20)) #time
data$treat <- as.factor(rep(c("C","T"), 50)) #treatment

summary(lmer(v1 ~ treat*date*time + (1|plot), data))
```

Summary returns this error message:

fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 20 columns / coefficients

```
Anova(lmer(v1 ~ treat*date*time + (1|plot), data))
```

Check the effect by running Anova function:

There is no value in time and interactive effect of time

```
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 20 columns / coefficients
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: v1
                 Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
treat           0.0063  1     0.9370
date            4.2765  4     0.3699
time                    0           
treat:date      2.8640  4     0.5808
treat:time              0           
date:time               0           
treat:date:time         0
```

I'm trying to find the reason why this has happened, but I'm not so sure what the problem is.

It seems model structure error or the way what I'm doing is wrong.

Has anyone idea? I don't have a strong statistical background, so I feel so lost in this analysis.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is always a good idea to explore your data.  You can learn much about the interdependencies simply by tabulating them, as in `with(data, table(date, treat, time))`.  You will find many rows of zeros, indicating redundancy (and showing exactly how it occurs).

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. In this case, how can I deal with this dataset? Is there any way to remove those redundancies?

Comment: Short of collecting additional data, there is no reasonable way to fit your model, because your data are whatever they are: you cannot change them.  The redundancies mean you are using a model that uses too many parameters.  This often is referred to as lack of *identifiability* and is traceable to an inadequate *experimental design*.

Comment: @whuber I see. For this kind of inadequate data collection, I can only analyze more simplified model like ~ treat * date or ~treat * time. Right?

Comment: That's correct.